# Building a Pyramid with CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a very simple pyramid construction kit. The user can add a block or remove one.

This works fine using the code below. However, currently I am specifying the next block's width using css (.item1 {200px;}, .item2 {300px;}. The problem is, I don't know how many blocks the user will add eventually and therefore, I cannot specify this in CSS. I would like to calculate the width of each additional block's width based on the previous block's width + 100px (previous width + 100px). Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this...Any help would be appreciated.

[simple pyramid pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiByF.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Add Block Functionality
  $('#add-block .button').click(function() {
    var $block = $('<li><div class="item"><input class="input" type="text" placeholder="#" maxlength="2"></div></li>');
    $('.pyramid').append($block);
    $('ul li div').addClass(function(index) {
      return "item" + index;
    }) //this is to increase the item to item 1, item2, item3 etc.
  });

  //Remove Block Functionality
  $('#remove-block .button').click(function() {
      $('.pyramid li').last().remove();
    }

  )
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item0 {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
}

li div.item:not(.item0) {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 0;
}

.item1 {
  width: 200px;
  /*plus 100px to create the trapezoid*/
}

.item2 {
  width: 300px;
  /*plus 100px to create the trapezoid*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pyramid">
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="buttons">
  <div id="add-block">
    <span>Add Block</span>
    <div class="button">+
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="remove-block">
    <span>Remove Block</span>
    <div class="button">-
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last `.item` width then append your desire number `var lastwidth = $('.pyramid li:last-child .item').width();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Add Block Functionality
  $('#add-block .button').click(function() {
    var lastwidth = $('.pyramid li:last-child .item').width();
    
    if(lastwidth == null){
    var plus = 0;
    } else {
    var plus = lastwidth + 100;
    }
    
    var $block = $('<li><div class="item" style="width:' + plus + 'px"><input class="input" type="text" placeholder="#" maxlength="2"></div></li>');
    $('.pyramid').append($block);

    
    //$('ul li div').addClass(function(index) {
    //return "item" + index;
    //}) //this is to increase the item to item 1, item2, item3 etc.
  });

  //Remove Block Functionality
  $('#remove-block .button').click(function() {
      $('.pyramid li').last().remove();
    }

  )
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item0 {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
}

li div.item:not(.item0) {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 0;
}

.item1 {
  width: 200px;
  /*plus 100px to create the trapezoid*/
}

.item2 {
  width: 300px;
  /*plus 100px to create the trapezoid*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pyramid">
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="buttons">
  <div id="add-block">
    <span>Add Block</span>
    <div class="button">+
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="remove-block">
    <span>Remove Block</span>
    <div class="button">-
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This does work and I looking at the code, I do understand why it does and how. However, I would have never come up with this myself. Thank you very much. One thing I have noticed though is, that I need to change the number from 100 to 190 (var plus = lastwidth + 190); for the trapezoids to line up smoothly. Again, I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: @Rummel17 Your welcome, glad to help. If you set to `190` .. this number is higher than zero, and next item will be => 190 x 2, and this make look bad, in this case you should set `var plus = 0;` to `90` at least, But it's up to you. anyway, if this answer solved your question, please check answer as accepted and vote up.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you told me. However, since my score is below 15, its only recorded but not displayed. Thank you again. I really learned a lot from your code.